# Catched NodeJS Errors still propagate?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I catch an error in two places, still, it seems to propagate further on to my socket server, killing it. Below is a incomplete summary of my code. Apologies for failing to providing a true minimal reproducable example I could not trigger it in simple terms.

### Outer catch

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';

export const run = async (ws: WebSocket) => {
  const executor = new Executor()
  
  const execution = executor.execute()

  try {
    for await(const update of execution) {
      ws.send(update.stringify())
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("Outer catch", error)
  }
}
```

### Executor (Inner catch)

```
class Executor {
    async *execute() {
        const promise = generator.next()

        // Handle run error
        promise.catch((error: Error) => {
          console.log("Inner catch", error) 
        })
    }
}
```

### Result (order of errors)

```
Log: "Inner catch", <THE_SAME_ERROR>
Log: "Outer catch", <THE_SAME_ERROR>!!
Error: <THE_SAME_ERROR>!!!

[nodemon] app crashed
```

What are some reason this could be happening?

### Edit

Im trowing the error on purpose, its as simple as

```
throw Error('Some message')
```

This error will be thrown in `generator.next()` above, which returns a promise that I don't await. Hence, Im registering the catch callback just after.

Comment: What are you returning yielding in `Executor.execute()`?

Comment: Im yielding an object. Here is the full source with types: https://github.com/ajthinking/data-story/blob/8579747005c53286d02a92907463ae831674286a/core/Executor.ts#L31

Comment: Could you share the areas where you throw the error - `throw Error('Some message')`

Comment: What is "THE_SAME_ERROR"? I understand that you are throwing an error with 'Some message' but is there also an error at that point that is coming from node? Maybe it would help if you shared that piece of code where you are throwing the error on purpose

Comment: In my case it is thrown thrown under specific conditions from here: https://github.com/ajthinking/data-story/blob/25e89e074d67589910cdf58bc115a9c6c9c91b1a/core/computers/Throw.ts#L13. But as to not narrow the question I am interested in ANY situation that might cause errors to propagate/not be stopped by catch-clauses. Im suspecting some async issue, race condition or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer to my problem and I don't understand why, but I could fix my issue by chaining `then` and `catch`. Compare these examples:

### Failing

```
(async () => {
  // The async generator
  const computer = async function *run() {
    throw Error('Some error!')
  }

  // Initialize the generator
  const runner = computer()

  // Store reference to the promise
  const promise = runner.next()

  // Handle success
  promise.then(() => {
    console.log("Handle success")
  })

  // Handle fail    
  promise.catch((error: Error) => {
    console.log("Catch", error)
  });

  // Await Error/Success
  await promise;
})();
```

### Succeeding

```
(async () => {
  // The async generator
  const computer = async function *run() {
    throw Error('Some error!')
  }

  // Initialize the generator
  const runner = computer()

  // Use chaining!
  const promise = runner.next()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Handle success")
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      console.log("Catch", error)
    });

  // Await Error/Success
  await promise;
})();
```

Comment: The problem is that you didn't show the correct code in the question. When you have a promise and call a `then()` you get *a new promise* out of it. When you call a `.catch()` you also get a new promise. So `promise`, and `promise.then()` and `promise.catch()` are three promises. Only the last one has a rejection handler attached to it, the other two don't, thus if `promise` gets rejected that's unhandled and the rejection also propagates to the promise from `promise.then()` and is also unhandled. Yet the question showed no code that could be diagnosed.

Comment: Thank you VLAZ for the explanation, it makes total sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to expand your try/catch scope to:

```
export const run = async (ws: WebSocket) => {
  try {
    const executor = new Executor();

    const execution = executor.execute();

    for await (const update of execution) {
      ws.send(update.stringify());
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Outer catch", error);
  }
};
```

And probably share a bit of context of your error message

Comment: Certainly, thanks for the idea, though the error occur in `for await (const update of execution)` so those statements are fine

Comment: Updated question with error